# В моем коде идет очень много запросов к базе данных. Как уменьшить кол-во запросов?

Tags: php

В моем коде идет очень много запросов к базе данных. Как уменьшить кол-во запросов?

```
public function CheckTime()
{
    $db = $this->db;
    $now = time();
    $sql = "select * from `db_product_time` where `status`=1 and `date_del`<=$now";
    $db->Query($sql);
    $arr = array();
    if ($db->NumRows()>0)
    {
        while($row = $db->FetchArray()) 
        {
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    if (count($arr)>0)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $row) 
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $par = $row['name'];
            $user = $row['id_user'];
            $sql = "update `db_users_b` set `$par`=`$par`-1 where `id`=$user";
            $db->Query($sql);
            $sql = "update `db_product_time` set  `status`=0 where `id`=$id";
            $db->Query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы корова давала больше молока и меньше ела, надо её чаще доить и меньше кормить.

Этим запросом вы, судя по всему, снимаете с некой публикации продукты (товары?) пользователя:

```
update db_product_time set status=0 where id=$id
```

И делаете это в цикле, т.е. по одному запросу на каждый такой товар. Можете для начала собрать идешки всех товаров и сделать один большой запрос вида:

```
update db_product_time set status=0 where id IN (<id товаров через запятую>)
```

Так запросов станет в 2 раза меньше; `(n-1)/2+1` если быть точнее.

Далее. В этом запросе, если я правильно угадал смысл, вы актуализируете число активных товаров юзера:

```
update db_users_b set $par=$par-1 where id=$user
```

Но это можно сделать отдельным запросом с `count(*)`'ом на число активных в настоящий момент товаров. И тоже один раз сразу для всех юзеров. Примеров полно даже тут рядом, например, [MySQL: Count records from one table and then update another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216175/mysql-count-records-from-one-table-and-then-update-another)

Итого:

- Ищете идешки юзеров и их товаров, которые надо деактивировать
- Перебираете эти идешки, накапливаете в 2 массива
- Одним запросом меняете статус всем товарам
- Одним запросом обновляете число активных товаров у каждого затронутого юзера

Comment: Вы абсолютно верно прочитали мой код, да я новичок и по сути мне нужно только одно действие которое критически важно не должно пройти дублированно:
update db_users_b set $par=$par-1 where id=$user
где $par = это разные породы "коров" и те что уже отработаны нужное количесво каждой породы и определенных пользователей: $user нужно убрать одним запросом.. Не могли бы Вы мне хоть примерно написать как должен выглядеть мой массив и как запрос?